pg_restore completes without any errors but data not loaded --Data Only --Dump file
In source the table1 has 4k records
Exported data using pgadmin:
C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\runtime\pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\Users\\~\\Documents\\data_20240619_1205.dump" --host "xx.xxx.xx.xxx" --port "6524" --username "devadmin" --no-password --format=c --blobs --data-only --verbose --table "myschema.table1" --table "myschema.table2" --table "myschema.table3" "source_databse_name"
200mb dump file got generated data_20240619_1205.dump
Imported using the below command (from my laptop) in command prompt:
export PGPASSWORD='my_password'
C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v7\runtime> pg_restore -U devadmin -h "xx.xxx.xx.xxx" -p 6524 -d target_database_name --data-only -v -n myschema --data-only --verbose --table "myschema.table1" --table "myschema.table2" --table "myschema.table3" -Fc "C:\\Users\\~\\Documents\\data_20240619_1205.dump"
pg_restore: allocating AH for C:\\Users\\~\\Documents\\data_20240619_1205.dump, format 1
pg_restore: read TOC entry 0 (ID 7032) for ENCODING ENCODING
pg_restore: read TOC entry 1 (ID 7033) for STDSTRINGS STDSTRINGS
pg_restore: read TOC entry 2 (ID 7034) for SEARCHPATH SEARCHPATH
pg_restore: read TOC entry 3 (ID 7035) for DATABASE **source_database_name**
pg_restore: read TOC entry 4 (ID 6979) for TABLE DATA table1
pg_restore: read TOC entry 5 (ID 6982) for TABLE DATA table2
pg_restore: read TOC entry 5 (ID 6982) for TABLE DATA table3
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore

In target still the table 1 has 0 records
Note:
Both source and target databases are in the same hostname
Both source and target databases uses the same userid to execute the export and import
Not sure why in the pg_restore source_databse_name is mentioned --Mentioned in bold

During pg_restore, you need to omit the schema name. So instead of --table "myschema.table2, you have to use --table "table2".
See the note in the documentation:

This flag [-t] does not behave identically to the -t flag of pg_dump. There is not currently any provision for wild-card matching in pg_restore, nor can you include a schema name within its -t. And, while pg_dump's -t flag will also dump subsidiary objects (such as indexes) of the selected table(s), pg_restore's -t flag does not include such subsidiary objects.


It is working now... Thanks a ton !!!

Also i noticed my export (which resulted in 200mb) took 50 minutes but the import took only 3 minutes. In my opinion this export:import time is exact opposite to oracle's export:import time ratio

There must be something strange during the export. Either a high-level lock on a table that gut released after 49 minutes of waiting, or the I/O system has severe problems, or the CPU on the source system is totally overloaded.

But what if my db.dump file already has schema name(schema_name.table_name)? How can I use pg_restore?

@SergeyChe I don't think a dump file can have a schema name.
